# R installation won't let me open packages library issue

Tags: r, installation, install.packages, library-path

Hi so I'm having trouble with R studios on my desktop where it won't let me open any packages.
When I attempt to install a package with install.packages()  like `Tidyverse` I get this error.

> Error in library("tidyverse") : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
> Show in New Window Error in install.Rtools() : could not find function
> "install.Rtools" Show in New Window WARNING: Rtools is required to
> build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and
> install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/athen/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/tidyverse_1.3.1.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 430128 bytes (420 KB) downloaded
> 420 KB

Then when I try to load the package into my library with library("tidyverse") I receive this error

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
> unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure: The specified module could not be found.

This error isn't just for `tidyverse` but all packages I try to run. I have uninstalled R and RStudios multiple times, but the error doesn't go away. I have been to IT at my university and they were completely baffled. Please help if you can, I really need R to work for both my job and classes.

Comment: not clear from your question, you're not using `library` to attempt to install packages, right? did you successfully install r tools and complete the other steps to make sure it is in your path before installing packages?

Comment: I used install.packages(), then library("tidyverse") in an attempt to load the package.  when I run find.package()
 and .libPaths() I get [1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/graphics" 
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/grDevices"
[3] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/utils"    
[4] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/datasets" 
[5] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/methods"  
[6] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.2/library/base"         
[1] "C:/Users/athen/Documents/R/win-library/4.1"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library"

Comment: "I used install.packages()" -- does this mean you used `install.packages("tidyverse")` and that completed successfully?

Comment: I think so I get this comment when i ran it WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

Comment: https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/athen/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/tidyverse_1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 430128 bytes (420 KB)
downloaded 420 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\athen\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpm6KXzr\downloaded_packages

Comment: Something seems very off about your R installation. How did you install R? Did you download directly from https://cloud.r-project.org/? What OS version are you running? Include the output of `sessionInfo()` so we can see the version of packages installed. Do you have a .Rprofile file in your home directory? Are you running as a regular user or with a privileged account? Are you using R directly or RStudio?

Comment: so I can't run sessionInfo() i get  Warning in La_library() :
  unable to load shared object 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.2/modules/x64/lapack.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
Error in La_library() : LAPACK routines cannot be loaded. I'm using R studio

Comment: I downloaded from  cloud.r-project.org, and I don't have a privileged account. My operating system is a 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: R used to run perfectly for me and then on Friday I ran into an issue where I couldn't load any new packages I was trying to install xslx. In an attempt to resolve the issue I reinstalled R.