# Loading Packages issues Continued LoadLibrary failure: The specified module could not be found

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I have previously posted about an issue I have in R in which I can't load any packages and I have fatal errors. I have tried installing r multiple times to no avail. You can see the previous post here. [R installation won't let me open packages library issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70282130/r-installation-wont-let-me-open-packages-library-issue)

When I have tried restarting R-studios or terminating the session. It fails to terminate and I receive this error I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this issue and what is going on.

```
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Do you have all the same problems if you open and work in R directly? (Not RStudio) How about your PATH variables? Is rTools in a PATH? (Is the correct rTools in PATH?) If rtools is a problem, that will lead to LoadLibrary failures. You can check PATH through R: `pkgbuild::find_rtools()` along with `pkgbuild::rtools_path()`. If `pkgbuild` finds rtools, but you still receive rtools errors when installing packages, then add the path information to your question. You may need to write or modify your `~./.Renviron` If that occurs, add the R, RStudio, and rtools versions, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just install Rtools?
Try these instructions: `https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/`
P.S., the PATH is not the PATH to the file location and should look as:

```
writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}/usr/bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```